# How Do not call function except storage the script in local storage completed?

Tags: javascript, arrays, ajax, local-storage

I do not want to call function `LoadLocal();` unless the task `window.localStorage.setItem( 'scriptjs', Base64.encode(xmlhttp.responseText) );`
 really has been completed. How?

```
function loadServer() {
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE ) {
           if (xmlhttp.status == 200) {
               window.localStorage.setItem( 'scriptjs', Base64.encode(xmlhttp.responseText) );
               loadLocal();
           }
           else if (xmlhttp.status == 400) {
               loadLocal();
           }
           else {
               loadLocal();
           }
        }
    };

    xmlhttp.open("GET", "http://tokojs.com/app/hokinawafashion.js?"+Math.random(), true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```

I do not want to call function `LoadLocal();` unless the task `window.localStorage.setItem( 'scriptjs', Base64.encode(xmlhttp.responseText) );`
 has been completed. How?

This is full script

```js
var Base64={_keyStr:"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/=",encode:function(r){var t,e,o,a,h,n,c,d="",C=0;for(r=Base64._utf8_encode(r);C<r.length;)t=r.charCodeAt(C++),e=r.charCodeAt(C++),o=r.charCodeAt(C++),a=t>>2,h=(3&t)<<4|e>>4,n=(15&e)<<2|o>>6,c=63&o,isNaN(e)?n=c=64:isNaN(o)&&(c=64),d=d+this._keyStr.charAt(a)+this._keyStr.charAt(h)+this._keyStr.charAt(n)+this._keyStr.charAt(c);return d},decode:function(r){var t,e,o,a,h,n,c,d="",C=0;for(r=r.replace(/[^A-Za-z0-9\+\/\=]/g,"");C<r.length;)a=this._keyStr.indexOf(r.charAt(C++)),h=this._keyStr.indexOf(r.charAt(C++)),n=this._keyStr.indexOf(r.charAt(C++)),c=this._keyStr.indexOf(r.charAt(C++)),t=a<<2|h>>4,e=(15&h)<<4|n>>2,o=(3&n)<<6|c,d+=String.fromCharCode(t),64!=n&&(d+=String.fromCharCode(e)),64!=c&&(d+=String.fromCharCode(o));return d=Base64._utf8_decode(d)},_utf8_encode:function(r){r=r.replace(/\r\n/g,"\n");for(var t="",e=0;e<r.length;e++){var o=r.charCodeAt(e);o<128?t+=String.fromCharCode(o):o>127&&o<2048?(t+=String.fromCharCode(o>>6|192),t+=String.fromCharCode(63&o|128)):(t+=String.fromCharCode(o>>12|224),t+=String.fromCharCode(o>>6&63|128),t+=String.fromCharCode(63&o|128))}return t},_utf8_decode:function(r){for(var t="",e=0,o=c1=c2=0;e<r.length;)o=r.charCodeAt(e),o<128?(t+=String.fromCharCode(o),e++):o>191&&o<224?(c2=r.charCodeAt(e+1),t+=String.fromCharCode((31&o)<<6|63&c2),e+=2):(c2=r.charCodeAt(e+1),c3=r.charCodeAt(e+2),t+=String.fromCharCode((15&o)<<12|(63&c2)<<6|63&c3),e+=3);return t}}

var versi = '1';
// Load Script Local
var sc = localStorage.getItem('scriptjs'); 
function loadLocal(){
 if (sc === undefined || sc === null || sc.length === 0){
  loadServer();
 }
 else{
    var s = document.createElement('script');
    s.type = 'text/javascript';
    var code = Base64.decode(sc);
    try {
      s.appendChild(document.createTextNode(code));
      document.body.appendChild(s);
    } catch (e) {
      s.text = code;
      document.body.appendChild(s);
    }
  }
 }
//

// Load Script Server
function loadServer() {
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE ) {
           if (xmlhttp.status == 200) {
               window.localStorage.setItem( 'scriptjs', Base64.encode(xmlhttp.responseText) );
      loadLocal();
           }
           else if (xmlhttp.status == 400) {
      loadLocal();
           }
           else {
      loadLocal();

           }
        }
    };

    xmlhttp.open("GET", "http://tokojs.com/app/hokinawafashion.js?"+Math.random(), true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
//

window.onload = loadServer();
```

Comment: don't put `loadLocal()` in your `else if` or `else` blocks and it wont be called

Comment: I mean, I want to call `loadLocal();` if `scriptjs` value really already completed set. But in fact called `loadLocal();` so quickly until `scriptjs` considered null.

Comment: your problem isn't that things are called too quickly - your problem is (probably) that you call `loadServer` function, and expect it to run synchronously - I can assure you that, in the case of status == 200, `window.localStorage.setItem` is run, and then `loadLocal` is run ... you need to know how to deal with asynchronous code

Comment: I has shown the complete source code in question and hope understand.

Comment: well, there's a difference in loadServer function ... the issue is, after you`window.localStorage.setItem` you don't update the `var sc` - so loadLocal has no way of knowing the var has changed ... try adding `sc = localStorage.getItem('scriptjs');` as the first line of load local

Comment: You're right, I have misplaced `var sc = localStorage.getItem('scriptjs');`